# Can the holder(s) of a Student Pilot Certificate, properly endorsed for solo flight privileges, participate in a Formation Flight?

Tags: faa-regulations, student-pilot, flying-in-formation

In the U.S., is it legal for the holder(s) of a Student Pilot Certificate, properly endorsed for single engine airplane solo flight privileges (in accordance with the training/proficiency requirements specified in [FAR 61.87](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/61.87) (d) (1-15),  and having received no specific training in formation flying by the CFI), to (while soloing), participate in a **formation flight** (assuming a specific limitation against formation flying is not included in the Student's logbook by his/her CFI)?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133581/discussion-on-question-by-757toga-can-the-holders-of-a-student-pilot-certifica).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under §91.111 (a)-(c), this arrangement is permissible both on solo and dual flights by a student pilot, provided both PICs make the required arrangements to do so and neither PIC carries passengers for hire during a formation flight.

Now the instructor endorsement for solo privileges in your logbook presents a problem. If it states you do not have formation flight privileges during solo flight operations, you are prohibited from conducting formation flying when serving as pilot and command (solo) as a student.

Comment: Does this mean that the endorsement would have to specifically allow formation flight, or only that the endorsement must not explicitly prohibit it?